# How can we enable UCI interface available on openwrt on ubuntu.

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, openwrt

How can we enable UCI interface available on openwrt on ubuntu. Currently, I installed libuci and libubox, with which I am able to get and set configuration parameters for files under /etc/config in ubuntu. But these values are not reflected in system services when I do a service restart. For example I set some values in /etc/config/network and /etc/config/dhcp . But /etc/init.d/networking reload, the system is picking up values from /etc/dnsmasq.conf and /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: UCI was specifically developed for use on OpenWrt. It won't run on Ubuntu unless you are attempting to port it, which is not a trivial task since it [ubuntu] is managed my systemd.

Answer (score 2):

You can run uci in Ubuntu by following the instructions available in ([external link](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/uci)). Make UCI in UBUNTU 16.04 , Raspbian Jessie or similar.

- First make a directory for download source codes

  mkdir ~/Desktop/uci
- Install json-c

Install the required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install dh-autoreconf git
```

Download source code:

```
cd ~/Desktop/uci
git clone https://github.com/json-c/json-c.git
```

Make and install json-c:

```
cd json-c
sh ./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
make check
```

- Install libubox

Install the required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install lua5.1 liblua5.1-0-dev cmake
```

Download source code:

```
cd ~/Desktop/uci
git clone https://git.openwrt.org/project/libubox.git
```

Install libubox

```
cd libubox
cmake .
make
sudo make install
```

- Install uci

Download source code:

```
cd ~/Desktop/uci
git clone https://git.openwrt.org/project/uci.git
```

Make and install uci:

```
cd uci
cmake .
sudo make install
```

Now you can use uci :

```
uci
```

If you still see this message:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libubox.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

edit this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Add this command into it:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

or this file

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

Add these commands into it:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then restart your computer.